# How can I create a url with extension for an audio/wav object fetched from API properly?

Tags: javascript, redux, fetch, redux-saga, audiowaveform

My task is to fetch an audio/wav file from an API call, store it in redux state and on button click play it.

1. I have the following redux saga generator function fetching it and creating a blob right now:

```
export function* getAudioSaga () {
    try {
        const headers = {
            Accept: 'audio/wav',
        };
        const options = {
            headers,
            method: 'GET',
        };
        const audio = yield call(fetch, GET_AUDIO_API, options);
        const blob = yield audio.blob();
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

        yield put(getAudioSuccess(url));
    } catch (error) {
        yield put(getAudioError(error));
    }
}
```

2. With getAudioSuccess action I save the created url into the redux state and I simply pass the stored url to a helper function:

```
export const playAudio = (url: string) => {
    const audio = new Audio(url);
    audio.play();
};
```

Right now I get an error if I try to use this generated blob url:
**Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.**

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: what is the `call` function? I must say, this is the oddest looking method of using fetch I've ever seen though `when it's in the state` what state? what is "it"? what are you passing to `playAudio`?

Comment: Why not just use an audio element with a source to play the file? They can be controlled programmatically too afaik. The fetching/url creation doesn't really serve any purpose. Plus you're not supposed to cram huge amounts of data into the redux state.